# Calculate the latitude,longitude 1000 kilometers east from a given location

Tags: distance, latitude-longitude

I am trying to calculate what would the Google maps latitude and longitude be, for a given location, 1000 east from it. I am not looking for an application which can do, this, but rather a manual way, by using equations.

I found out that there is a way of doing this, if one would know the initial bearing Angle:

```
bearingAngle = 90
d = 1000 kilometers / 6371 kilometers
x = asin( sin lat1 * cos d + cos lat1 * sin d * cos bearingAngle)
y = lon1 + atan2( sin bearingAngle * sin d * cos lat1, cos d - sin lat1 * sin x)
```

(Equations are taken from: movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html, section "Destination point given distance and bearing from start point")

However, the upper equations are giving the following result:

[image]

As you can see the "x,y" location has a bit lower latitude then starting "lan,lon" (Paris).
Basically this is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

The problem is that, to do this, I need to know the initial "bearing angle", which I do not.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: A thousand kilometers is a long distance to travel using a spherical earth model.  The [geodetic inverse problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesy) could solve the bearing and distance between two points short of antipodal distance, much as the direct geodetic problem can solve location for strating point, distance, and bearing.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Vince.
The "Second (inverse) geodetic problem" you are mentioning requires the second point (its latitude and longitude) to be known. Which is not known in this case.

Comment: If you don't know the point *or* the bearing, the problem can't be solved.

Comment: If you use units of **radians** in computer trig functions, they're more likely to produce correct results.

Comment: All upper variables are in radians (except for the "d" - angular distance).
I checked the calculated "x","y" variables on Google maps. And they correspond the upper first photo.

I thought this problem could have been solved somehow by replacing "x" to be equal to "lat", and from there (by using a formula for bearingAngle) somehow calculating the "bearingAngle", and after that "y".

Comment: I guess what you need is the intersection between the circle of the same latitude in WGS84 as the starting point and a circle with the radius of 1000km in an azimutal equidistant projection around the starting point.

Comment: Thank you for the reply AndreJ. Is is possible to calculate this by using equations?

Comment: I prefer to do those things using GIS software like QGIS.